# Convention over configuration and the making the user's own convention

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

i am doing convention based coding where if u want a module then just you have to derive from the interface called IModule . And i will find all the Modules by scanning then in the runtime and will form the URL out of it.

In this case i have to register my URL with the name of the class(something like Asp.net MVC) by removing the Convention for Eg: if u have a CustomerModule i will remove the Module and register your URL as "/Customer". But i want to give the flexiblity for the user to change that Convention .

```
if (instance.Name.EndsWith("Module")) -- this is filter
{
  int instanceCount = instance.Name.IndexOf("Module"); -- action
  routeCollection.Add(new RouteDefination(instance.Name.Remove(instanceCount)));
}
```

The user can give any filter and the i need to take the action accordingly.. How can i do it .I can use expression or if u have any design patten . it will be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Provide a method/property in the interface that provides a readonly name.

```
public interface IModule
{
    /* other methods */
    string Alias { get; }
}
```

Or follow Java's approach with Servlets and allow user's to specify an XML file that you parse and allow overrides that way (e.g., `<module name="CustomerModule" alias="Picky" />`). Or both.

Comment: I strongly believe tat Conventions are better than asking them to name  it.two things about it. 1) Making your program understandable.2)Framework know What to do..(What if they forget to give the alias name)

Comment: I was under the assumption that this was meant to be optional. I agree that the default should be the convention. You could provide the Alias as an extended IModule (e.g., `IAliasedModule : IModule`) and simply check for it when assigning the name. Or require that `Alias` be `null` for default.